# Kafka Streams as table Patch log not full Post

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Desired functionality: For a given key, key123, numerous services are running in parallel and reporting their results to a single location, once all results are gathered for key123 they are passed to a new downstream consumer.

Original idea: Using AWS DynamoDB to hold all results for a given entry. Every time a result is ready a micro-service does a PATCH operation to the database on key123. An output stream checks each UPDATE to see if the entry is complete, if so, it is forwarded downstream.

New Idea: Use Kafka Streams and KSQL to reach the same goal. All services write their output to the results topic, the topic forms a change log Kstream that we KSQL query for completed entries. Something like:

```
CREATE STREAM competed_results FROM results_stream SELECT * WHERE (all results != NULL).
```

The part I'm not sure how to do is the PATCH operation on the stream. To have the output stream show the accumulation of all messages for key123 instead of just the most recent one?

KSQL users, does this even make sense? Am I close to a solution that someone has done before?

Comment: Sounds like an aggregation to me.

Comment: It is an aggregation, but can you aggregate a large variable number of topics easily? From what I can tell, Kafka allows you to aggregate 2 topics into 1, which you could do multiple times, but I'm not sure about merging 20 topics, or 50 topics.

Comment: An aggregation is an operation on one topic, not multiple. Hence, I am not sure if I understand your comment. Your question does not mention multiple input topics either.

Comment: I misunderstood how an aggregations work, I thought they would merge the contents for a key from 2 topics. Can you explain how you would use an aggregation for my scenario so I can better understand? @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: If you use a single topic, all your services can write into this topic -- you would use the key to ensure add data you want to aggregate is written into the same partitions. Afterward, you process the data with KSQL or Kafka Stream and collect all data for one key and emit it downstream. I guess, that using Kafka Streams as `builder.stream("inputTopic).transform(...).to("outputTopic")` may be the best approach (with an attached state store to the `Transformer`---and maybe using a punctuations). How so you know that you have seen all data for a single key and that your can write the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you can produce all your events to the same topic, with the key set, then you can collect all of the events for a specific key using an aggregation in ksqlDB such as:

```sql
CREATE STREAM source (
    KEY INT KEY,  -- example key to group by
    EVENT STRING  -- example event to collect
  ) WITH (
   kafka_topic='source', -- or whatever your source topic is called.
   value_format='json' -- or whatever value format you need.
);

CREATE TABLE agg AS
  SELECT 
    key, 
    COLLECT_LIST(event) as events
  FROM source
  GROUP BY key;
```

This will create a changelog topic called `AGG` by default. As new events are received for a specific key on the source topic, ksqlDB will produce messages to the `AGG` topic, with the key set to `key` and the value containing the list of all the `events` seen for that key.

You can then import this changelog as a stream:

```sql
CREATE STREAM agg_stream (
   KEY INT KEY,
   EVENTS ARRAY<STRING> 
) WITH (
   kafka_topic='AGG',
   value_format='json'
);
```

And you can then apply some criteria to filter the stream to only include your final results:

```sql
STREAM competed_results AS 
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM agg_stream 
  WHERE ARRAY_LEN(EVENTS) = 5; -- example 'complete' criteria.
```

You may even want to use a [user-defined function](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/udf/ksql.html) to define your complete criteria:

```sql
STREAM competed_results AS 
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM agg_stream 
  WHERE IS_COMPLETE(EVENTS);
```